# Success not being returned from ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

AJAX Post is not returning success call in wordpress. I have the following code and I can get to the first dialog box in testing, but no mater what I do its not getting to the second. It's not finding the function in `functions.php` even though I have it declared.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#send_btn").click(function(){

    var datastring = $("#redemmpointsForm").serialize();

      var points = $('#points').val();
      var comments = $('#comments').val();

          jQuery.ajax({
             type : "post",
             dataType : "json",
             url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
             data : {"action": "redeempoints", "points":points},
             success: function(response) {
                if(response.type == "success") {
                 alert('do i get here');
                }
                else {
                   // Do something else
                }
             }
          });
    });
     }); //Modal event Ends
```

functions.php file

```
wp_localize_script( 'inkthemes', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')));

function functionRedeempoints() {

die();
return true;
}

add_action("wp_ajax_functionRedeempoints", "functionRedeempoints");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_functionRedeempoints", "functionRedeempoints");
```

**Ok so i treid the following**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#send_btn").click(function(){

var points = jQuery('#points').val();
var comments = jQuery('#comments').val();

         var allData = {
   action: 'functionRedeempoints',
   points: points,
   comments:comments
}
       var data = JSON.stringify(allData);   

           alert( data);

          jQuery.ajax({
             type : "post",
             dataType : 'json',
             url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
             data : data,
             success: function(response) {
            if(response.success) {
             alert('do i get here');
            }
            else {
               // Do something else
            }
         }
      });
});
 }); //Modal event Ends
```

And iN MY FUCNTIONS php Its like its not fidning the php function.

```
  wp_localize_script( 'inkthemes', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')));

function functionRedeempoints() {
wp_send_json_success(true);
}

add_action("wp_ajax_redeempoints", "functionRedeempoints");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_redeempoints", "functionRedeempoints");
```

Comment: you should jsonencode your php result because you dataType is json

Comment: What are you getting in `response` variable before `if(response.type == "success")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your function functionRedeempoints does not return anything that the ajax call can handle.

It just dies even before the return statement.
Also a return by the PHP end will never actually be interpreted by the JS. JS can only read from the http request, so you need to actually write to it by an echo statement.

Wordpress provides a convenient way of handling this for you:
What you need would be something like:

```
function functionRedeempoints() {
   wp_send_json_success(true);
}
```

This already takes care of stopping execution and properly JSON encoding your response.

Also the correct response handling on the JS side is a little different than in your example code.
You can find the details on this here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json_success

But what it boils down to is that the success is encoded in the result.success property of the response.

Hence you want your check to be

```
if(response.success)
```

instead of `if(response.type == "success")`

With these changes your example should work though :)

Working example ( in plugin form) based on your code:

Put this in hello.php in the plugins folder

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Ajax demo
*/

function test_load_js() {
    wp_register_script( 'ajax_demo', plugins_url( 'hello.js' ), array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax_demo', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax_demo' );
}

function functionRedeempoints() {

    wp_send_json_success( true );
}

add_action( "wp_ajax_functionRedeempoints", "functionRedeempoints" );
add_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_functionRedeempoints", "functionRedeempoints" );
add_action( "init", "test_load_js" );
if ( ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
    echo '<input type=button value="send" id="send_btn">';
}
```

Put this in hello.js in the plugins folder

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#send_btn").click(function () {

        var points = jQuery('#points').val();
        var comments = jQuery('#comments').val();

        var data = {
            action: 'functionRedeempoints',
            points: points,
            comments: comments
        };

        alert(JSON.stringify(data));

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    alert('do i get here');
                }
                else {
                    // Do something else
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this helps you to get a start here, works just fine when you click the button that should appear on the upper left of your admin screen ( zoom in ;) )

Comment: your on the right path but its almost as if its not gettting to find the php function and i dont no why as its not even getting the result true :-(

Comment: Try removing this part:  
```var data = JSON.stringify(allData);```

Just put the allData in the data property of your Ajax call. No need to manually stringify this, and it could in fact be causing problem.s

Comment: i have done but no joy this is really annoying me now

Comment: How do you enqueue your script?

Comment: wp_localize_script( 'inkthemes', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')));

function functionRedeempoints() {
 wp_send_json_success(true);
}

add_action("wp_ajax_funcitonRedeempoints", "functionRedeempoints");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_funcitonRedeempoints", "functionRedeempoints");
its get to jquery but its likes in never finds this is in my functions.php

Comment: i already show this in my above answer how i do in function php the scrpt is laoded fine and getting to first message fine but its not finding the function in function.php !

Comment: Updated with working example, sorry hard to figure what specifically went wrong in your use case but you should be able to figure it out from the above :)

Comment: its not a plugin im working on its a inline form in a page template

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference : Just put it in plugin form so you can try it out in a more isolated scenario and then move it to your page template.
If it works in this form and not in your page template, you can be sure you're simply enqueuing the JS wrong in some way or another.
Work from above code though, yours contained additional minor issues like a wrong case in the localization objects name.

Comment: well i did a small test and strange it insterted the value into the db but again didnt return a value back which is quite odd :-(

Comment: Database ? :) That seems to be a different issue right ?
At any rate, ajax working now ?

Comment: yeah i got ajax working that armin i put it in a pluigin insteasd as you stuggested just have to figure out validation and how to give a noification to end user that its done.